# How can I output hello world in this simple React code?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[image]I used create-react-app from npm to start a new react project. I wanted to use this to do the learn react course on Scrimba. I installed everything without any problems. I deleted all the src files as ill be copying new ones from Scrimba but I kept absolutely everything else.

I currently have the following in my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<div><h1>Hello world!</h1></div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and a html file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>placeholder</h1>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.pack.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I load the html file, I can see 'placeholder', but not 'Hello World!'
I've also included an image of the file layout. I also included a screenshot in case my layout or something is wrong. Any help appreciated!
(I've already posted almost the same problem but was advised to post a better/updated version)

Comment: create react app compiles into the index.html file located in your public folder. you do not need to create an index.html in your source folder.  React instead expects jsx.  I highly suggest reading some documentation

Answer (score 2):

There already is an index.html file in your public folder. No need to create a new one.

You should start looking at your index.js file. It points to app.js, which is an example react component you can start editing and playing around with.

Make sure to open a terminal and start your react app with **npm install** followed by **npm start**.

I would suggest reading some documentation. The official react website is great. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment instead.

Comment: I actually didn't know there was already an index.html in public, so i just created one. I pressed cmd i to run the file (not sure if thats what you mean by load though).

Comment: My bad, wanted to help OP but I'm not able to comment yet.